# Navigation stack should use which node map_server or map_saver

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In navigation stack I am using a launch file. In that launch file map_server package is launching map_server node.

For creating map I am using gmapping package. In Gmapping I am using map_saver node from map_server package to save a map. I am in confusion that in Navigation stack which node of map_server package I should  use map_server or map_saver.

What is the difference between map_server and map_saver?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242387/navigation-stack-should-use-which-node-map_server-or-map_saver/) by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

map_saver saves a map generated by gmapping to a file on the computer.
You can then use the map_server package for publishing this saved map for localization.

So in short map_saver saves a generated map, and map_server uses the saved map.

---

Originally posted by [FOXTER](https://answers.ros.org/users/26976/foxter/) with karma: 153 on 2016-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on 2016-08-25**:
Thank  you